# How can I write a Protractor test that finds the first element in an 'ng-repeat'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to figure out how I can take the following view.html below, and test for the column and row position (.col , .row) if the first element/tile.

```
<div class="container" gridster="gridsterOpts">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <tile tilevalue="{{tile.tileId}}" gridster-item="tile" row="{{tile.row}}" col="{{tile.col}}" size-x="{{tile.sizeX}}" size-y="{{tile.sizeY}}" ng-repeat="tile in selectedTiles"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Any ideas how this can be done? I don't know how to use the repeater call, i'd imagine that's where the solution is derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a Protractor-specific question - you can use the built-in [`by.repeater()` locator](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) and get the `first()` element:

```
var firstTile = element.all(by.repeater("tile in selectedTiles")).first();
```

Then, to get the `row` and `col` attribute values, use [`getAttribute()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute):

```
firstTile.getAttribute("row").then(function (row) {
    console.log(row);
});
firstTile.getAttribute("col").then(function (col) {
    console.log(col);
});
```

Or, if you want to assert the values:

```
expect(firstTile.getAttribute("row")).toEqual("0");
expect(firstTile.getAttribute("col")).toEqual("0");
```

Comment: thanks! this is along the right path, but how can i write the expect() for this, so that I test whether or not that element is in row 0 column 0 per say

Comment: @KO12 sure, please see the updated answer. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ng-repeat call in Angular simply generates the appropriate html to display the relevant information.  As such, your ElementFinder (or ElementFinders) simply need to select the row, col that you need using ByCss.

See the example from w3schools and inspect the result. http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_repeat_array

You'll see that the following angular code

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Creates this html:

```
<ul>
  <!-- ngRepeat: x in names -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="x in names">Jani</li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: x in names -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="x in names">Hege</li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: x in names -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="x in names">Kai</li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: x in names -->
</ul>
```

So your ElementFinder will be:

```
element(by.Css('ul li'));
```

or

```
element(by.Css('ul li tile'));
```